# pexpect cmd taking longer to run as compared to command directly run on the machine

Tags: pexpect

Hi have a command which I am running using pexpect as follows,

```
      options = '-q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null - 
      oPubkeyAuthentication=no'
      timeout = 50
      file = open('sshlog.txt', 'w')
      ssh_cmd = 'ssh %s@%s %s' % (user, host, options)
      child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_cmd, timeout=timeout,encoding='utf8')
      child.logfile = file
      child.expect(['[pP]assword: '])
      child.sendline(password)
      child.expect(".*#")
      child.sendline("echo 'cmdstart'; cat <some command> ; echo $?; echo 'cmdend'")
      child.expect('.*#')
      cmdoutput = child.after
```

Here, my pexpect is timing out after 50 seconds as the command run is still not complete. However, the same command is getting completed in a few seconds when directly on the server.

Can someone help here ?